# kendo ui mvvm table rows iteration no data on input tag

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui

I am iterating through an array to show tables and also the rows in each of them.

It seems that all is good until the second iteration (so problem starts from the second table displayed), where the `input`'s that I have in two `td`'s don't show the data anymore, not the values I am passing nor the `data-role: switch`.

Example code:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="some-id-table">
# for (var j = 0; j < firstArray.length; j++) { #
    # var item = firstArray[j] #
    <div>
        <h3>#= item.info #</h3>
        # if (item.details.length > 0) { #
            <table id="item#=j#">
                //....                    
                <tbody>
                    # for (var i = 0; i < item.details.length; i++) { #
                        # var detail = item.details[i] #
                        <tr>
                            <td>#= detail.typeCode#</td>
                            <td>
                                <input
                                    id="#=detail.id#"
                                    type="number"
                                    title="" 
                                    min="0"
                                    onkeyup="X.something.viewModel.handleChangeAmount(event, #= j #, #= i #)"
                                    onchange="X.something.viewModel.handleChangeAmount(event, #= j #, #= i #)"
                                    data-idx="#= i #"
                                    data-bind="value: item[#= j #].details[#= i #].amount, 
                                            readonly: item[#= j #].details[#= i #].transit, 
                                            disabled: item[#= j #].details[#= i #].transit, 
                                            attr:{class: item[#= j #].details[#= i #].confirmed ? 'boldTxt' : ''}"
                                />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input
                                    id="#=detail.id#"
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    name="#=i#"
                                    parentIdx="#= j #"
                                    data-role="switch"
                                    data-bind="checked: item[#= j#].details[#= i #].confirmed, 
                                          disabled: item[#= j#].details[#= i #].disableConfirm, 
                                          events: { change: onToggleConfirmChanged }" 
                                >
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div
                                   data-actionsheet-context="#= serializeContext(detail) #">
                                    <span>#= detail.positionState #</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    # } #
                </tbody>
            </table>
        # } else { #
            <div> No item information found. </div>
        # } #
    </div>
# } #
```

*(Tried to simplify code for clarity and there may be typos, but I hope you get the point about the `input` tags)*

Extra note: in the `data-bind` property of the `input` tags I have tried as well to reference `detail` like so: `value: detail.amount` with no success, so I maybe the `detail` reference breaks somehow after the first iteration? (`# var detail = item.details[i] #`) The other 2 columns (first  and last) are displayed correctly though.

Edit: To be more specific about what is wrong with the `input` tags, it's that the amount is not shown in the number input, and the second input is just a check box (without being correctly checked/unchecked) instead of being a switch.

Comment: You can't reference 'detail' in a binding like 'value: detail.amount' because 'detail' does not exist on the model the template is bound to. You created it as part of the template rendering and it's discarded when the templating is done. But that's not the problem. The fact that the 2nd iteration input tags are empty and the checkbox is not a switch means that kendo hasn't bound them but I can't see why. If you inspect the page with your browser tools, has the html been rendered as you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the template for the first input, the html generated will look like this:

```
data-bind="value: item[0].details[0].amount,
```

However 'item' does not appear to be part of the model that the template is bound to. You create it within the template and can use it to drive logic and inject its value into the html with '#=item#' but you can't use it in a binding declaration. From the first line of the template, it appears that 'firstArray' is part of the model. Hence I suggest you want this html instead:

```
data-bind="value: firstArray[0].details[0].amount,
```

So try replacing 'item' with 'firstArray' in your data-bind. What I think is happening is that kendo starts binding the rendered template and is breaking somewhere internally because of the invalid data-bind string. The bind then stops and the rest of your html (the second iteration) doesn't get done. You may see some kendo errors if you check the console or have a debugger attached.